# Python math is correct in command line while painfully wrong in py file?

Tags: python

I was working on a projects on r/dailyprogrammer. 
I copied one of the coded for reference and try to run it but it did the math wronngly.

```
def N_queens_validator(n):
```

(...) this part I try to illustrate the board

```
if len(set(n))!=len(n):
    return print(f'{n} =>False same row')

else:
    origin=[(ind,val) for ind,val in enumerate(n)]
    a=origin[:]
    for m in range (len(n)):
        root=a.pop(0)
        for i in range(m+1,len(n)):
            result=root[0]-origin[i][0]/root[1]-origin[i][1]
            print(str(root[0]-origin[i][0])+'/'+str(root[1]-origin[i][0])+'the result is: '+str(result))
            if  np.abs(result)==1:
                return print(f'{n} =>False same diagonal')
    return print(f'{n} =>True')

N_queens_validator([8, 6, 4, 2, 7, 1, 3, 5])
```

and here is the result which is just non-sense at all. Obviously the math was done wrongly
[The result of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgHSD.png)

Comment: `thing+thing/thing+thing` is a different thing from `(thing+thing)/(thing+thing)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems with your code:

1) You need, as user2357112 says, to put parentheses around the two subtractions so that the subtractions are done before the division.

2) You had a typo in your print statement.  `str(root[1]-origin[i][0])` should be `str(root[1]-origin[i][1])`

Here's the fixed version of your code:

```
def N_queens_validator(n):

    if len(set(n))!=len(n):
        return print(f'{n} =>False same row')

    else:
        origin=[(ind,val) for ind,val in enumerate(n)]
        a=origin[:]
        for m in range (len(n)):
            root=a.pop(0)
            for i in range(m+1,len(n)):
                result=(root[0]-origin[i][0])/(root[1]-origin[i][1])
                print(str(root[0]-origin[i][0])+'/'+str(root[1]-origin[i][1])+' the result is: '+str(result))
                if abs(result)==1:
                    return print(f'{n} =>False same diagonal')
        return print(f'{n} =>True')

N_queens_validator([8, 6, 4, 2, 7, 1, 3, 5])
```

Result:

```
-1/2 the result is: -0.5
-2/4 the result is: -0.5
-3/6 the result is: -0.5
-4/1 the result is: -4.0
-5/7 the result is: -0.7142857142857143
-6/5 the result is: -1.2
-7/3 the result is: -2.3333333333333335
-1/2 the result is: -0.5
-2/4 the result is: -0.5
-3/-1 the result is: 3.0
-4/5 the result is: -0.8
-5/3 the result is: -1.6666666666666667
-6/1 the result is: -6.0
-1/2 the result is: -0.5
-2/-3 the result is: 0.6666666666666666
-3/3 the result is: -1.0
[8, 6, 4, 2, 7, 1, 3, 5] =>False same diagonal
```